# ONNX C# :How Do I go about reading this object and extracting the probability value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, random-forest, onnx, onnxruntime

I've saved an ONNX-converted pretrained RFC model and I'm trying to use it in my API. I am able to call the saved model and make my prediction however I can't get my predicted value. The response is very complicated and I can't seem to figure it out.
Here's the predicted value shape in debug mode:
[image]

and here it is in python, I'm trying to get the second value:

[image]

This is what I've tried so far but I only get string values.

```
        var result = _inferencesession.Run(new List<NamedOnnxValue>
        {
            NamedOnnxValue.CreateFromTensor("input", attritionData.AsTensor())
        });
        var scoreValue = result.LastOrDefault().Value;
        var score = scoreValue.GetType()?.GetProperty("Value")?.Attributes;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it !
I had to use AsEnumerable and then access the values I wanted:

```
       var seq = result.LastOrDefault().AsEnumerable<NamedOnnxValue>();
        var map = seq.First().AsDictionary<Int64, float>();
        var values = map.First().Value; //this is what I want
```